# Removable module about android

Tags: android

I want to have a removable module which can dynamically add listview.The module can be moved to left or right.How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: You could put it in a FrameLayout in your main view and set conditions for its visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please learn about How to add Android Layouts dynamically. In your case You can use Relative Layouts to control the child views position and other layout parameters. You can get help from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html